# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined ajax get request

Tags: jquery, ajax, get, undefined, typeerror

I'm keep getting uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '1' of undefined for the following line:

```
data.rows[j].experiment[experimentNo] = {
  "experimentName": {
    "goal": goal_entry,
    "strategy": strategy_entry,
    "experiment_name": experiment_name,
    "hypothesis": hypothesis_entry,
    "audience": audience_entry,
    "kpi": kpi_entry,
    "pages": pages_entry,
    "experiment_link": expt_link_entry,
    "status": status_entry,
    "test_brief_link": test_brief_entry
  }
}
```

I'm fairly new to this and I've tried making changes based on other posts with the same issue such as setting an empty array first, but nothing seems to work. Note that I'm essentially trying to get data and manipulate it to produce the desired output. See below for the entire ajax request that this belongs to:

```
$.ajax({
  type: "GET",
  url: "url",
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(data) {
    var teams = Object.keys(data.rows).length;
    for (j = 0; j < teams; j++) {
      var teamid = data.rows[j].id;
      if (entryid == teamid) {
        var experimentNo = Object.keys(data.rows[j].doc.experiment).length;
        var experimentList = data.rows[j].doc.experiment;
        data.rows[j].experiment[experimentNo] = {
          "experimentName": {
            "goal": goal_entry,
            "strategy": strategy_entry,
            "experiment_name": experiment_name,
            "hypothesis": hypothesis_entry,
            "audience": audience_entry,
            "kpi": kpi_entry,
            "pages": pages_entry,
            "experiment_link": expt_link_entry,
            "status": status_entry,
            "test_brief_link": test_brief_entry
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Example of json output:

```
{
"total_rows": 4,
"offset": 0,
"rows": [
{
  "id": "218db2ac87c373d8b015e1f3d0f37a1c",
  "key": "218db2ac87c373d8b015e1f3d0f37a1c",
  "value": {
    "rev": "2-453783d12591c400ff0283a1bc6755ae"
  },
  "doc": {
    "_id": "218db2ac87c373d8b015e1f3d0f37a1c",
    "_rev": "2-453783d12591c400ff0283a1bc6755ae",
    "business_unit": "china",
    "team_name": "china2",
    "team_number": "china2",
    "experiment": {
      "experimentname1": {
        "goal": "goal1",
        "strategy": "strategy1",
        "exptname": "exptname1",
        "hypothesis": "hypothesis1",
        "audience": "audience1",
        "kpi": "kpi",
        "pages": "pages1",
        "exptlink": "exptlink1",
        "status": "status1",
        "testbrief": "testbrief1"
      }
    }
  }
},
{
  "id": "4683dd4fa0446efc3ed7dd24a94aabc8",
  "key": "4683dd4fa0446efc3ed7dd24a94aabc8",
  "value": {
    "rev": "1-57471567a501230e5405b0e518dc6cf0"
  },
  "doc": {
    "_id": "4683dd4fa0446efc3ed7dd24a94aabc8",
    "_rev": "1-57471567a501230e5405b0e518dc6cf0",
    "business_unit": "cloud",
    "team_name": "clou2",
    "team_number": "clou2",
    "experiments": ""
  }
},
{
  "id": "77f6455bbb80db982d1a2c3604cfbe90",
  "key": "77f6455bbb80db982d1a2c3604cfbe90",
  "value": {
    "rev": "1-5e1cdb086f97c13175d8bb8a4a569dc3"
  },
  "doc": {
    "_id": "77f6455bbb80db982d1a2c3604cfbe90",
    "_rev": "1-5e1cdb086f97c13175d8bb8a4a569dc3",
    "business_unit": "bluemix",
    "team_name": "Bluemix1",
    "team_number": "Bluemix1",
    "experiments": ""
  }
},
{
  "id": "9382855b57442ab3e054a4a366fa6cfd",
  "key": "9382855b57442ab3e054a4a366fa6cfd",
  "value": {
    "rev": "1-223523bc661e179d94ae63dbeda55cf5"
  },
  "doc": {
    "_id": "9382855b57442ab3e054a4a366fa6cfd",
    "_rev": "1-223523bc661e179d94ae63dbeda55cf5",
    "business_unit": "china",
    "team_name": "china1",
    "team_number": "china1",
    "experiments": ""
  }
}
```

]
}
Thank you!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show a sample of the JSON. Is `data.rows` supposed to be an array, as implied by looping over it like that? If so, why are you using `Object.keys(data.rows).length` instead of just `data.rows.length`?

Comment: Sorry, yes - you're absolutely right, I can use data.rows.length as it is an array.  I edited above to show example of json

Comment: OK, well looks like the problem line is missing `.doc` before `.experiment`. I think that accounts for the error. Though saying `.experiment[experimentNo] = ...` seems a bit odd when the `experiment` property is *not* an array. (Also, some of the items in the outer array don't have an `experiment` property at all.)

Comment: oh wow. I totally miss that....thanks for pointing it out! Those were just some test entries I threw in there.  Eventually there would be multiple "Experiments" within that array. Thanks again!